# Does hive have any api to check a sql but not execute it?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am looking for an api that check the submitted sql but no need to excute it. When my users submit a sql I need to tell them if sql is correct in real time, then I need to save the sql and excute the sql in future. So if hive api have this features ?

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN <query to be checked>` would meet this requirement of yours.

Hive provides an EXPLAIN command that shows the execution plan for a query. When a query is executed with `EXPLAIN` at the start of it, the query is initially checked for any syntax errors and then the execution plan is shown as the result. This way, users will be able to check if the query they have written is correct and also if it is efficient for execution from the execution plan. (No actual execution of the query happens here)

To read more about `EXPLAIN`, you can refer [HERE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain#LanguageManualExplain-EXPLAINSyntax)

**Sample output of a query with `EXPLAIN`**:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test_table;

STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
2     Stage-0 is a root stage
3   
4   STAGE PLANS:
5     Stage: Stage-0
6       Fetch Operator
7         limit: -1
8         Processor Tree:
9           TableScan
10            alias: test_table
11            Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 15812 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
12            Select Operator
13              expressions: id (type: int), name (type: string), email_preferences (type: struct<email_format:string,frequency:string,categories:struct<promos:boolean,surveys:boolean>>), addresses (type: map<string,struct<street_1:string,street_2:string,city:string,state:string,zip_code:string>>), orders (type: array<struct<order_id:string,order_date:string,items:array<struct<product_id:int,sku:string,name:string,price:double,qty:int>>>>)
14              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4
15              Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 15812 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
16              ListSink
```

Hope it helps!